# Internal CD drive will not play reliably when connected via USB

Tags: usb, cd-drive

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 and I scavenged an internal CD/DVD drive from a failed laptop. I wanted to connect it externally to a newer laptop which doesn't have an internal CD drive. So I got a SATA -> USB cable to connect the drive.
When connected, the system recognises it, but playback is unreliable, and either stutters, or stops after a few seconds.

`lsusb` reports

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1f75:0621 Innostor Technology Corporation
```

Any suggestions for diagnosing the problem/getting it working?

Comment: Does the cable you have go single SATA to single USB connector? Or Single Sata to 2x USB connectors. Most of the external CD/DVD drives I have seen have 2 USB connectors (one is data, one is additional power as sometimes the device needs more power than a single USB connector can provide). Although maybe USB 3 gives more power than USB 2 I am not sure. How many USB connectors do you have and is it connected to a USB 2 or USB 3 port? If USB 2 then try a USB 3 port.

Comment: It's a single SATA/USB cable. There are two USB ports on the laptop, one of which is SS (USB3), and the other is USB2. When connected to USB3, the drive fails to spin up (it tries to). When connected to USB2, it spins up fine, but I get playback problems.

Answer (score 0):

As codlord has stated, this is due to power constraints defined by the USB bus.

A little bit about power over USB:

- USB ports output a maximum of 5 volts of direct current (5V DC)
- USB ports on *some* notebooks (most notably Toshiba and Fujitsu devices) have a maximum output of 3.3 volts when running on battery
- USB 1.0 and 2.0 can deliver "up to" 500 mA (0.5A) of current
- USB 3.x can deliver "up to" 900 mA (0.9A) of current

With these limits in mind, let's do some math:

| Version | Volts @ Amps | Watts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USB 1.0 | 5V @ 0.5A | 2.5 Watts |
| USB 2.0 | 5V @ 0.5A | 2.5 Watts |
| USB 3.x | 5V @ 0.9A | 4.5 Watts |

***Note:** The notebooks that cut USB power to 3.3V when on battery are not part of the above chart. It is also important to state that not all manufacturers stick to these limits. Some USB ports will supply a smaller number of amps in an effort to reduce total power consumption and/or thermal conductivity issues.*

Now let's look at the typical optical drive for notebooks. Yours identifies as being from `Innostor Technology Corporation`, which is sometimes branded as "LiteOn". A quick search online shows that many of their notebook optical drives have the following power profiles:

| State | Power Consumption |
| --- | --- |
| Connected / Idle | 0.3 Watts (± 10% depending on brand & model) |
| Reading (CD/DVD) | 2.5 ~ 3.0 Watts |
| Writing (CD/DVD) | 2.75 ~ 4.0 Watts |
| Reading (Blu-ray) | 3.0 ~ 4.0 Watts |
| Writing (Blu-ray) | 4.5 ~ 6.3 Watts |

So, with all this said, connecting the device and having it announce itself to a computer requires almost no power. Once the disc starts spinning, though, the device will demand more power. If the motor that spins the media is consuming the bulk of the energy from the port, then there will not be enough remaining for the laser or its actuator carriage. It is for this reason, as codlord mentioned, that a lot of external optical drives will have two USB cables; one for just power, and the other for both data and power.

This answer is probably overkill ...

Comment: A USB-A/USB 3.x can supply more than 900 mA.  900 mA is the _minimum_ a USB-A port must supply to meet the USB 3.x spec.  USB 3.x allows for 1.5 A from USB-A and 3.0 A from USB-C before needing to use USB-PD, USB-BC, or some other protocol to negotiate for more power.  USB 2.0 also allows for negotiating for 1.5 amps on USB-A, I don't recall if it allows for more current on USB-C.  I'm getting conflicting answers on what the maximum current a single USB-A port is allowed to source by USB specs, it may be 2.4, 3.0, or 5.0 A.

Comment: Please don't use USB Y-cables to try to get more power to your drive, it's often just a waste of money as they rarely work to provide more power.  USB Y-cables violate the USB spec and can permanently damage hardware.  Instead try a powered USB hub, find a proper power supply for the drive, or use a different SATA adapter that can supply more power.  A Y-cable rarely works because USB devices are supposed to ask for more power before taking it, and a computer cannot detect if a Y-cable is in use to give permission for using more power.

Comment: Looking at your power figures, a USB3 port should be able to deliver enough power for this device to play a CD.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions for diagnosing the problem/getting it working?

I'd suggest a drive enclosure with power supply.  Here's something like I'm thinking of:

Drive enclosure -> https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/VLSSTOPTU2/

Power supply -> https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MOTGPWR/

The drive enclosure above comes with a USB Y-cable as a power option but don't use it, these violate the USB spec and so rarely work and run the risk of damaging your computer.  I have not used this product myself so I don't know how well it works, I provide the link as an example of what to look for and because I'm a happy customer of Other World Computing.